Projections of intersection of planes and a cylinder on xz and yz planes
I'm seeking assistance to calculate the projection on the xz and yz planes of the region defined by the intersection of the planes $z=x+y+1$, $z=x+y+2$, and the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$. How can I find these projections analytically?
Is there a systematic method to approach projections of 3D shapes onto planes surfaces, particularly when visualization is challenging?
Thank you.

Hi! For orthographic projection just drop one axis, e. g. to xz-plane drop y, to yz-plane drop x.

The $xz$-plane is the plane $y = 0$. Lines perpendicular to this plane have the form $t \mapsto (x_0, t, z_0)$ with $x_0, z_0$ constant. So if $p=(x,y,z)$ is a point being projected onto the plane, the line of that projection has $x, z$ constant along it. So the projection is the omtersection of that line with $y = 0$. I.e., it is the point $(x, 0, z)$. So all you have to do to get the projections is set $y = 0$ in the equations. Similar behavior occurs for the $yz$-plane. But remember that the third equation is a cylinder, not a circle.
